# Make changes to a LISP code for AutoCAD, it is possible?

Tags: lisp, autolisp

I have a LISP code for AutoCAD, but I want to change it a bit.

The objective of the LISP is to export the data, at the press of a button, to create the line in autocad (just as you see on the file "comparison.pdf"). The spans before and after the donut and the angles are on the file test "file test.xls".

[Link for the four files that I quote - "file test. xls", "vepl_formexcell_rev02.lsp", "column A - name of donut.jpg" and "comparison.pdf"](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U-xrQUDKH-XjVVvUKa6quZWJ3ebDyHlU?usp=sharing)

I want to make this changes:

1. It should have a donut on the (0,0) point in autoCAD, with a value assigned.
2. The number of the donuts should be the ones on column A of the excel, as per image "column A - name of donut.jpg" in attachment. If the first value on the column B is 0, then the name of the first donut should be the one on A3. If it is different then 0, the value on the donut in (0,0) point should be A2 minus 1.
3. The values on the D column shows the angle of the line. But, the angle should be in correlation with the angle of the line prior. I sent you an pdf named "comparison.pdf", comparing what it is creating with what it should be created. Analyze it and correct the code accordingly, please. Note that the dimensions presented are for your understanding, you do not have to present them.
4. The value of the angles - when the value is negative, it should go upwards (left), when it is positive, it should be downwards (right).

I think that the example that I send (comparison.pdf) is helpful in understanding all this.

Can someone help me please? It is for my thesis.

I have tried different iterations with the help of ChatGPT, but because I am not a very good programmer, I can't do it.

Comment: Please post a [mre] here, not just a link to an external site.